# running tsc on all files in the folder

Tags: typescript, tsc

I've found various tutor websites which refer to the **tsc** command to run and watch for source file changes. Nevertheless, when I write:

*tsc -w or tsc --watch*

I'm getting messages in the command line asking to write the filename (in all the tutors I've seen it is not the case). As such, tsc does not compile the json file, for example, in the folder.

What am I missing?

I'm running version 2.9.6.

Comment: Do you have `tsconfig.json` in the same directory where you are running `tsc`?

Comment: Yes. All files in the same folder

Comment: Please include the tsconfig